# all of items are not list up in Recycler viewer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i created Recycler view that shows the item list, however, only first top 10 are shown if i drag down the list repeat the randomly first 1~10 items, it should be shown like that

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

12

13

....

but

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10  (till here good)

5

3

6
....(only repeating 1~10 number)

i attached the code, can someone get me the advice??

```
private RecyclerView mItemRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ItemAdapter mAdapter;
private TextView mTitleTextView;
private TextView mCostTextView;
private Button mBuyButton;
private Button mSellButton;
private Button mUse;
private Button mLeaveButton;
private GameData gmd;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);

    gmd = (GameData) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("gamedataToMarket");

    mItemRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mItemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    List<Item> items = gmd.getItems();

    mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(items);
    mItemRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    mLeaveButton =  findViewById(R.id.leave_Button);
    mLeaveButton.setText(R.string.leave);
    mLeaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            Intent rtn = new Intent();
            rtn.putExtra("gameDataReturnFromMarKet",gmd);
            setResult(1,rtn);
            Toast.makeText(marketActivity.this, "back to navigation from market", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });

    FragmentManager fm2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment2 = fm2.findFragmentById(R.id.status_recycler);
    if(fragment2 == null){
        fragment2 = new status_fragment();
        fm2.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.status_recycler,fragment2)
                .commit();
    }




}

private class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private Item mItems;

    public ItemHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        mCostTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
        mBuyButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_1_option);
        mBuyButton.setText(R.string.bought);
        mBuyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(marketActivity.this, R.string.bought, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mSellButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_2_option);
        mSellButton.setText(R.string.sold);
        mSellButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(marketActivity.this, R.string.sold, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        // function for sell item
            }
        });
        mUse = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_3_option);
        mUse.setText(R.string.use);
        mUse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(marketActivity.this, R.string.use, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void bind(Item item) {
        mItems = item;
        mTitleTextView.setText(item.getDescription());
        mCostTextView.setText(String.valueOf(item.getValue()));
    }
}

private class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemHolder> {
    private List<Item> items;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> item) {
        items = item;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.holdingview,parent,false);

        return new ItemHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/item_name"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:layout_weight="0.8"
android:padding="1dp"
android:text="item name" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/item_cost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="1dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="1dp"
android:text="cost" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_1_option"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_2_option"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_3_option"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you attach the UI what you want to achieve ?

Comment: yes i did, that number is simeple example not really want to show that. actually 2 text view show item name and cost, 3button have additional action. point is i create more than 15items but only 10items show on the list and rest of items are not appeared anywhere in the recycler viewer

Comment: @SandeepInsan   i edited the number example. i didnt mean horizontal, vertical list

Comment: Make changes in your code according to my answer it will work.
Checkout the https://github.com/saini2sandeep/Favourite project for a clean way of writing the RecyclerView code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your code like this:

1. In ItemHolder class you are passing "view" in super method but getting by id using 
   "itemView".You have to find the id of view by using the same parameter that you 
   passing in super method.
   so change all your findViewById like this:

   ```
   mTitleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
   mCostTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
   ```
2. You are declaring views (TextView and Button which you are using to populate data) in 
   activity and geting id in viewHolder.You have to declare them inside the viewholder.
   In your case do it like this :

   ```
   private class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   private TextView mTitleTextView;
   private TextView mCostTextView;
   private Button mBuyButton;
   private Button mSellButton;
   private Button mUse;

   public ItemHolder(View view) {
       super(view);
       mTitleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
       mCostTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_cost);
       mBuyButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_1_option);
       mSellButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_2_option);
       mUse = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_3_option);
   }
   }
   ```